# Matrix of integer powers

Tags: matrices, inverse, integers

Is there a name for the square matrix ($j=0...n$, $k=0...n$)

$M_{jk} = j^k$

(with special case $M_{00}:=1$) and is there a closed general formula for its inverse?

I have stumbled upon this while trying to find alternative discretizations of continuous transfer functions in digital signal processing theory. Does anyone know any other specific contexts where this matrix occurs? I am asking because this looks so familiar to me, but I can't remember where I have seen it.

Comment: How do you define $M_{00} \overset{?}{=} 0^0$?

Comment: It is a special case of a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: @RobertLewis: for k=0 it is defined as Mjk==1

Comment: @nicomezi: Yeah, Vandermonde sounds familiar to me. Thanks, I think that will guide me to further info.